# Handling duplicate GET requests (caused by Trendmicro) in a Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

What is the best strategy to deal with duplicate GET requests coming from the same client in an Apache Tomcat servlet?

Basically, what I'm getting are 2 request a couple of seconds apart, the first from the client's real IP, the 2nd from a TrendMicro server (this appears to be the same effect as described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39616/odd-duplicate-http-requests).

Now my servlet faithfully serves both requests but produces problems later on (because it calls another remote service which most likely cannot deal with this situation either).

So the question is, how can I block the 2nd request? Or is there any other strategy to address this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So I've just found that this is causing problems on my website as well. I store the current information that a client has requested in the session, but I was getting reports of seemingly random situations where a user would be looking at one customers information, go to view another customers information, add a comment, but the comment ends up on the 1st customers record.

I found the culprit today. It is TrendMicro, mirroring the call to the first customers record in between the real user viewing the second customers information and adding the comment. They also spoof the cookie, which is the main issue.

Ie. 1) Real IP calls Customer 1 info (info gets stored in session)

2) Real IP calls Customer 2 info (info gets stored in session, replacing customer 1 info)

3) TrendMicro IP calls Customer 1 info (info gets stored in session, replacing Customer 2 info)

4) Real IP adds comment, which gets added to the customer stored in session, which now, thanks to TrendMicro, is Customer 1.

The Solution? - I added a check to ensure that we only service calls originating from the IP address that logged in.

To do this, You need to do 2 things.

1) On your login code, after you have validated the login credentials, Store the users IP address in the session using this code:

```
session.setAttribute("LoginIPAddress", request.getRemoteAddr());
```

Next, write a class that implements the javax.servlet.Filter interface.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class ServletUserAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {


    // ----------------------------------------------------- Instance Variables


    /**
     * The default character forwardTo to set for requests that pass through
     * this filter.
     */
    protected String forwardTo = null;


    /**
     * Take this filter out of service.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        this.forwardTo = null;
    }

    /**
     * Select and set (if specified) the character forwardTo to be used to
     * interpret request parameters for this request.
     *
     * @param request The servlet request we are processing
     * @param result The servlet response we are creating
     * @param chain The filter chain we are processing
     *
     * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
     * @exception ServletException if a servlet error occurs
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();

        // Is there a valid session?
        // We now also redirect requests if the remote IP Address is not the same address that originally signed in
        if(!httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(httpRequest.getContextPath()+"/services/login") && !httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(httpRequest.getContextPath()+"/services/logout")
                && (((session==null || session.getAttribute("userData")==null))
                || (session!=null && session.getAttribute("LoginIPAddress")!=null && !session.getAttribute("LoginIPAddress").equals(httpRequest.getRemoteAddr())))){
            // An Https page has been requested, but no valid session has been found, ao forward the user to the page indicated by forwardTo
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)response;
            StringBuffer logonQuery = new StringBuffer();
            logonQuery.append(httpRequest.getScheme());
            logonQuery.append("://");
            logonQuery.append(request.getServerName());
            logonQuery.append(":");
            logonQuery.append(httpRequest.getLocalPort());
            logonQuery.append(httpRequest.getContextPath());
            logonQuery.append(forwardTo);
            session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("MESSAGE", "Your session has expired. Please login again");
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(logonQuery.toString());
            return;
        }

        // Pass control on to the next filter
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }


    /**
     * Place this filter into service.
     *
     * @param filterConfig The filter configuration object
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        this.forwardTo = filterConfig.getInitParameter("forwardTo");
    }


}
```

I have some extra check in this code that you may not need, but the main section check is !session.getAttribute("LoginIPAddress").equals(httpRequest.getRemoteAddr())

Finally, you need to make this code run each time your server receives a request by adding this to your web.xml

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Check User Has Logged In</filter-name>
    <filter-class>au.com.mySystem.utils.filter.ServletUserAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forwardTo</param-name>
      <param-value>/pages/loginForwarder.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
```

My code is now working correctly again (No thanks to TrendMicro)

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet is serving the requests directly a simple [rate limiting filter](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/filters/RequestRateThrottleFilter.java?r=416) will do the trick - instead of using a session like this change it to use the incoming requests method + path + ip and then create a second entry for the trendmicro ip.

However proper web servers are usually better at this so if you have one (eg nginx or apache) then I would look at doing it there or you could simply block the TrendMicro IP address (if its coming from the same IP)

Comment: Ok, I suppose this is a valid approach - although it would mean hardcoding the "offensive" Trendmicro IP(s).

Since this service is called by registered users only, I've now implemented a filter which uses the user's id to block duplicate requests while the first (real) request is still running.