# HttpServlet receiving 2 requests for each ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

FINAL EDIT : I was using log4j actually and it wasn't good configurated causing it to double log each LOGGER.debug();

I can't figure out why my servlet is receiving 2 requests for each ajax call my frontend send.

I run my Servlet with Tomcat.

My System.out.println() prints "Hello" two times when I connect myself with the front-end.

I verified multiple times with F12 in Firefox, I only send one ajax request with parameter action=register.

My HttpServlet :

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = { "/actions" })

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -983728805534985870L;



public MyServlet() {

}



protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    response.setContentType("text/html");



    switch (request.getParameter("action")) {

    case "call":

        callAction(request, response);

        break;

    case "register":

        System.out.println("Hello");

        register(request, response);

        break;

    case "unregister":

        unregister(request, response);

        break;

    }

}



private void callAction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    /*
    ...
    */

}

private void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String connectedUserNumber = request.getParameter("number");

    String uniqueID = agentUCC.register(connectedUserNumber);

    LOGGER.debug("Register request from " + request.getRemoteAddr() + " with phone number " + connectedUserNumber);

    LOGGER.info("User with phone number [{}] has been connected with uniqueID [{}]", connectedUserNumber, uniqueID);

    handleSuccess(response, uniqueID);

}



private void unregister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    /*
    ...
    */

}



// utility method - avoid code redundancy

private void handleSuccess(HttpServletResponse response, String message) {

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    try {

        response.getWriter().print(message);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        LOGGER.error("ERROR : {}", e.getMessage(), e);

    }

}
```

}

I'm testing it with a simple front-end :

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--  This will be displayed first. When the user isn't logged yet. -->
    <div id="connectionPage">
        <h2>Connection</h2>
        <br/>
        <p>Your phone number :</p>
        <input type="text" id="connectionNumber"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Connect" id="connect"/>
        <br/>
        <p id="connectionError"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- 
        ...
    -->

    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my script.js :

```
$(function() {
    var connectedUserNumber;    
    // session's ID
    var uniqueID;

    // Connection
    $("#connect").click(function(){
        connectedUserNumber = $("#connectionNumber").val();
        register();
    });

    // Register to the back-end
    function register(){
        console.log("Register !");
        $.ajax({
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo/actions',
            data: 'action=register&number=' + connectedUserNumber,
            datatype: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                uniqueID = data;
                doPoll();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, exception) {
               /*
            ...
           */
            }
        });
    }

    // Send every 2 seconds an ajax's request to retrieve incoming call's notifications
    function doPoll() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'foo/actions',
            data: 'action=getNotificationToPush&uniqueID=' + uniqueID,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                handleDoPollSuccess(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, exception) {
                handleEventError(jqXHR, textStatus, exception);
            }
        }).always(function() {
            // Waits 2 seconds before sending the next request
            setTimeout(doPoll, 2000);
        });
    }
    /*
    ...
       */
});
```

Do you guys have an idea of where this mights come from?
I can give more details if requested.

Edit : I ctrl + f + "register()" in my JS file and the only place I call this method is line 9. I would have seen this second ajax call in my Firefox Debug Console anyway.

Edit bis : both requests are received at the same thousandth of a second. (Eg : both are received at 14:40:30:859)

Comment: There is another user asking how to handle second requests from TrendMicro, a security framework. Do you have anything like that in your stack? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353652/handling-duplicate-get-requests-caused-by-trendmicro-in-a-tomcat-servlet?rq=1

Comment: No absolutly not. I added a detail : both requests are received at the same thousandth of a second. (Eg : both are received at 14:40:30:859)

Comment: You sure it's not just the OPTIONS request? I mean, what's in your JS console? It's pretty easy to see what's being sent from the browser.

Comment: Is `connect` also submit button?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure of what are the OPTIONS request... My ajax call is using the POST request.

Comment: @user7294900 No, it doesn't send anything. Nice try!

Comment: What's in your JS console for the requests? Ajax sends a pre-flight request.

Comment: your  connect button is being clicked twice for some reason

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte If it was being clicked twice, it would appear in the Firefox Debug Network Console Right?

Comment: Yeah you should see two post requests to your servlet, in the Network view. And if you're not seeing that, then the only possible explanation is that you're doing something funky server side. For example have you tried removing the case switch statement? What about not using the handleSuccess method?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Yeah, good idea, will try tomorrow and let you know ;)

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Ok, I find out what my problem was. I wasn't using System.out.println. Actually I used log4j. My log4j.properties wasn't well configurated causing it to log twice each actions.Sorry!

Comment: Makes sense. Glad to hear you figured it out. Happy coding!